# Check if first time someone goes to asp.net website?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello I am creating a basic counter that adds +1 everytime someone accesses the website. The problem is it adds 1 everytime someone goes to another page on the site, not when the person goes to the site for the first time, making the data very inaccurate (ex. One user that accesses the site may go to 8 different pages, therefore adding 8 to the counter, insead of 1). Is there a way to detect when a user is accessing the site on the first initial load?

I'm using asp.net 3.5 in C#.

Comment: Could you please clarify? Do you want to count each time a new user comes to your website? What if they come back the next day when their current session has timed out? Do you count them a second time?

Comment: Yes in this case it is to determine how many times the site is visited even if is the same person on a new session..Session_Start event is sounding pretty favorable..

Comment: Session_Start is working nice except it is only incrementing the counter when someone logs in. Is it possible to count un-authenticated users?

Comment: The Session_Start event should fire for both Authenticated and Unauthenticated users.

Comment: What is your Authentication mode?

Comment: My authentication mode is Forms.

Comment: Email me if you like and I can take a more thorough look at your code. See profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the Session_Start event in Global.asax.cs

```
    protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          //Increment your counter here

    }
```

This will add one to the counter for each user, the first time they hit a page on your site. Then, once the browser session has timed out (by default 20 minutes of inactivity on your site), another increment will occur the next time the hit your site. The timeout period is configurable.

If you want to do it for the first time they EVER hit your site, then the cookie approach mentioned by some other posters will do this. But remember, you have no way of knowing whether it is the same user, just the same computer - think Internet cafe.

**Edit:** Following your comment about anonymous users:
What are your authorizatioin settings? e.g.

```
<!-- Allow access to anonymous (unauthenticated) users. -->
<authorization>
  //probably shouldn't do this in particular, but you might want to look at your settings
  <allow users="*" /> 
</authorization>
```

Comment: True. Don't disable session. It is enabled by default, so this would be a good reason not to disable it.

Comment: @Chuck, session is a server-side concept, what do you mean by 'if session is disabled' ?

Comment: @rochal @Chuck is right. Session can't be disabled for my solution to work. Presumably the loyalpenguin wants the data on the server side?!! Not much point having it only in a cookie on the client side.

Comment: I'm not suggesting storing count in the cookie on the client. I'm suggesting that if a user comes to the page and does not have a session cookie, the user is not currently browsing the site. The mere existence of the session cookie tells the site, that the user is currently browsing the site and not to increment the count.

Comment: @Chuck, for this to work, Sessions must not be disabled, in which case there is no need for a cookie. It can all be done in the Session_Start event. The site doen't need the existence of a cookie to tell it the user isn't browsing the site. The Session_Start event tells them that, without having to write a single line of cookie access code.

Answer (score 2):

Set a cookie. Check for the cookie, if it's present, then don't increment the count.

If the user is required to login, you could count how many times they login.

Comment: Also, if a second user comes to your site on the same computer, say in an internet cafe, they won't be counted because the cookie will still be there.

Comment: @James - true, but who turns off their cookies nowadays? Most modern sites, depend on cookies.

Comment: @Daniel - not if you use session cookies. They expire once the user leaves the website or the browser is closed.

Comment: If you are using session cookies, then you can't have Session turned off and you may as well do it all on the server side in the Session_Start event (that is what it is for) as per my answer. There is no need in this case for a cookie.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to log by IP Address alone, because anyone behind a firewall is going to show up as the same IP Address.

I think cookies are the way to go here.  When a user first goes to your site, set a cookie.  For any request after that, only increment your counter if the cookie is not present.  Using Session_Start will give you similar behavior, but Session cookies expiration may lead you to track the same person multiple times.

If you could expand on what the purpose of the counter is, it would help in determining the proper solution.

Comment: If a second user comes to the site on the same computer, say in an internet cafe, they won't be counted because the cookie will still be there. The question states that they want to increment the counter "+1 EVERY TIME someone accesses the website" (My caps). In this case, the session is exactly what is required

Comment: @Daniel - not if they use a session cookie.

Comment: @Chuck, for this to work, Sessions must not be disabled, in which case there is no need for a cookie. It can all be done in the Session_Start event. The site doen't need the existence of a cookie to tell it the user isn't browsing the site. The Session_Start event tells them that, without having to write a single line of cookie access code.

Comment: I agree with you, I just think the initial question isn't entirely clear.  If I had to guess, I would think Session is ultimately what loyalpenguin is looking for, but there are scenarios (like what you mentioned) on that could make Cookies, Session, or IP less than ideal.

Comment: True, the penguin needs to clarify and the cookie monster needs to stay quiet for a little while, eh Chuck?

Comment: @Daniel - The irony is user session is tracked by ASp.Net with cookies. If this is a smaller site that is hosted on one server, then using session will work just fine. But once you cross over to the session darkside, it's hard to comeback.

Answer (score 0):

Store the IP address of all visitors, but only store unique IP addresses.

Comment: The won't be accurate. An router can mask n number of people behind an IP address.

Comment: True, but nothing is 100% accurate here, unless you get people to sign in with their names... or better still passport numbers since names aren't unique.  It's still a common solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/#utm_campaign=en_us&utm_source=en-ha-na-bk&utm_medium=ha&utm_term=google%20analytics). Very comprehensive tracking of your users, free (to a degree).